# Example of a locally compact but not locally connected group

Tags: locally-compact-groups

Does someone know any example of a locally compact but not locally connected group?

Thank you

Comment: Any locally profinite group, e.g. the additive group of a local field, the multiplicative group of a local field, $\operatorname{GL}_n$ of a local field (non-archimedean local fields)

Comment: The Cantor set is locally compact but not locally connected.

Comment: There are even connected locally compact groups that are not locally connected.

Comment: @EdwardEvans Not every locally profinite groups, every non-discrete locally profinite group ;-)

Comment: Thank you guys!